# How to get argument from launch-file not used in a Node?

Tags: python, ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I read a lot of questions about arguments and launch files and did not find something related to my case (maybe this one https://answers.ros.org/question/375591/how-to-get-argument-values-in-ros2/, but I can't get the value of the LaunchConfiguration)

So here is my pb, I want an argument be used in the launch file to loop on IncludeLaunchDescription instanciation -> I have a yml file working for 1 drone, and i want to use many drones.

```
def generate_launch_description():
    # ...
    arg_n_drones = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        "N",
        default_value="1",
        description="number of drones in the simulation."
    )  # this does not seem to be enough to have the argument visible with the --show-args option

    N = 1  # I would like something based on arg_n_drones
    l_include_drone_spawn = []
    for i in range(1,N+1):
        l_include_drone_spawn.append(
            IncludeLaunchDescription(
                "launch/spawn_drone.yml",
            )
        )

    return LaunchDescription([
        # ...
        *l_include_drone_spawn,
    ])
```

Any help appreciated,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/416863/how-to-get-argument-from-launch-file-not-used-in-a-node-?/) by [SébastienL](https://answers.ros.org/users/146607/s%C3%A9bastienl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2023-06-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First you need to add your declared argument to the final `LaunchDescription` that you return:

```
return LaunchDescription([arg_n_drones, *l_include_drown_spawn])
```

To use it in your launch file as a normal Python variable, I believe you must use `OpaqueFunction`:

https://answers.ros.org/question/415825/can-i-programmatically-call-a-launch-file-with-arguments-that-can-be-used-as-a-variable-for-python-operations/

https://answers.ros.org/question/416438/adding-node-from-within-opaquefunction-in-ros2-python-launch-file/

That second answer includes a concrete example of using a declared launch argument to do N things. There are a couple of ways to access its string value. You can use a `LaunchConfiguration` object inside your `OpaqueFunction` and use `LaunchConfiguration.perform(context)`:

https://github.com/danzimmerman/dz_launch_examples/blob/rolling/launch/opaque_multi_nodes.launch.py#L9

or you can access it by name from the `context.launch_configurations` dictionary:

https://github.com/danzimmerman/dz_launch_examples/blob/rolling/launch/arg_examples.launch.py#L24

(`LaunchConfiguration.perform(context)` accesses this internally, see [here](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/rolling/launch/launch/substitutions/launch_configuration.py#L96)).

---

Originally posted by [danzimmerman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37963/danzimmerman/) with karma: 337 on 2023-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SébastienL](https://answers.ros.org/users/146607/s%C3%A9bastienl/) on 2023-06-27**:
thank you, it was missing indeed. With the correction, the arg is in the output of ros2 launch -s.
Any idea on how to get its value ?

```
context = LaunchContext(argv=sys.argv)
arg_n_drones.visit(context)  # return None
```

**Comment by [danzimmerman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37963/danzimmerman/) on 2023-06-27**:
Updated my answer with info there. I am not sure there's any way besides `OpaqueFunction` to get a valid context. It's the only way I know.

Creating a new one in `generate_launch_description()` seems to give an empty dict for `context.launch_configurations` and a subsequent error:

https://github.com/danzimmerman/dz_launch_examples/blob/rolling/launch/multi_nodes_no_opaque.launch.py

**Comment by [SébastienL](https://answers.ros.org/users/146607/s%C3%A9bastienl/) on 2023-06-27**:
Well it seems my problem is solved thank you.
I'd already tried the solution with OpaqueFunction but i failed at the time. I suppose that forgetting to put my argument in the LaunchDescription was a prerequisite for testing the other solutions.
Your example files are very good, simple and clear !